# How to present a ViewController on the same UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have a view controller `homeViewController` with a navigation controller `homeNavigationController`. I need to present another view controller `playersListViewController` from `homeViewController`. But it needs a different navigation controller. How can I display them both under same navigation controller
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need a different navigation controller for second view controller?

Comment: can you explain `But it needs a different navigation controller` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need another Navigation Controller. Just create an instance of playersListViewController in homeViewController.m and push it onto your existing navigation controller. This should do it:

```
    playersListViewController *newListViewController = [[playersListViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newListViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I should have used pushViewController instead of presentViewController

Answer (score 0):

Add both to the storyboard embedded in their own navigation controllers. Then programmatically present the second view controller.

You will need to find a way to dismiss the presented view controller and the correct way to do that is by having homViewControler dismiss it via a protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I'm exactly not sure why `it needs a different navigation controller`, but if you really need to have the second `viewController` on a separate `navigationController`, try presenting the second `navigationController` itself into the current `navigationController`.